# If I override .equals(), do I need to override .hashCode() even if I don't use a HashMap?

Tags: java

If I choose never to store my objects in the collection, do I need to override hashcode or can I have the same hashcode for my objects? Is it good or bad for performance?

Comment: You don't need to override hash code if you are sure the object is never ever going to be used in the future in any hash based collection. There isn't any performance impact either. However, it is a good practice to override them together so that the contract exposed by the method is honored.

Comment: Why the heck is "how does it affect performance" so frequently among the first things programmers ask when faced with a decision?

Answer (score 5):

It is not absolutely necessary, but it is better practice to do so if you ever decide to store and sort the objects later.

Answer (score 5):

Is it absolutely necessary? No.

Is it a best practice? Yes.

Will it come back to bite you if you don't in 6 months? Maybe.

Comment: Best response ever seen there. Also this comment is a SPAM

Answer (score 4):

[Equal objects must have equal hash codes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29); this is the contract for any class.

If you're feeling too lazy to implement a decent `hashCode` method you can still conform to the contract with this implementation:

```
  @Override public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
  }
```

It will perform poorly in hash-based collections but will at least be correct.

Answer (score 2):

it will not take much effort for you if you always override these methods, more so modern IDE provide to you this functionality

Answer (score 1):

No you should provide hash code. you never know about tomorrow you may need to use it there

Answer (score 1):

If `A.equals(B)`, then `A.hashCode() == B.hashCode()` must be true.

If `!A.equals(B)` though, `A.hashCode() == B.hashCode()` can still be true.

If you don't override `hashCode()` when you override `equals()` then putting things into some collections will actually lose the objects (they won't retrieve). So either override `hashCode()` properly, or just override it to `return 1`. This will satisfy the constraints and work correctly, but be terrible for performance if you start putting alot of them in a hash-based collection.

Answer (score 1):

To address this point:

> Is it good or bad for performance?

Either you need it or you don't. If you need it, you don't have a choice. If you don't, it will never be called anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some others have mentioned just returning a constant value. This might lead to some confusion later on over performance if you forget and put it in a hash based collection. I would consider throwing an UnsupportedOperationException so that if you do want to use it later, you will find out pretty quickly so you can go ahead and do a proper implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you override hashcode you also need to override equals. Hashcode must return the same value for comparison for which equals returns true, or hashmaps will not work properly.

Yes. Override hashcode if you can improve upon the default implementation.